# onsubmit() does not call my function but the form does get submitted

Tags: forms, onsubmit

I have a external js file that has the following function in it. It is supped to be called by the forms onsubmit but it doesn't appear to be happening. The form is just submitted without validation. At one point this was working but now it is not. Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
function validateDelete(form)
{
alert("Validation Started!");
var photoName=form.deleteName;
if (photoName === "")
{
    alert("Photo Name Required");
    return false;
}
}


  <script src="galleryScripts/validation.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <form action="galleryScripts/deletePhoto.php?submit=true" name="deleteForm" onsubmit="return validateDelete(this);" id="deleteForm" method="post">
    <label>
    File Name: <input name="deleteName" type="text" id="deleteName">      
    </label> 
    <label>                       
    <input type="submit" name="deleteButton" id="deleteButton" value="Delete" />                 
    </label>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your js is included.

For example under mozilla press CTRL+U and click on a link to your validation.js file.

Also you can just paste in  tag in your  tag it should work.

Comment: The js file being included wasn't the problem. I'm thinking that this has something to do with the js file being cached in my browser.

Comment: function validateDelete(form)
    {
    var photoName = form.deleteName.value;
    if (photoName.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Photo Name Required");
        return false;
    }
    }